# How do I output values separated by words?

Tags: c#

I am trying to get the output like this:

> 4 then 5 then 6 then 7 then 8 then 9 then 10 then 11 then 12 then 13.

The biggest challenge I'm facing is to make sure the word "then" doesn't appear after the last number (13).

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int start;

       for(start = 4; start<=13; start++)

           Console.Write(start +" then " );

       Console.ReadKey();
    }       
}
```

Comment: Console.Write(start + (start<13 ? "then" : ""));

Comment: Please take a look at [ask] and write a title that makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       string result = "4";

       for(int start = 5; start <= 13; start++)
       {
          result += " then" + start;
       }

       Console.Write(result);

       Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply add for a condition for `13` since you don't wanna add `then` after it like;

```
for (start = 4; start <= 13; start++)
{
     if(start == 13)
     {
        Console.Write(start);
     }
     else
     {
        Console.Write(start + " then ");
     }
}
```

Outout will be;

> 4 then 5 then 6 then 7 then 8 then 9 then 10 then 11 then 12 then 13

Answer (score 2):

Use `String.Join` to combine your values. It only adds the separator *between* the elements:

```
Console.Write(String.Join(" then ", Enumerable.Range(4, 10)));
```

Note: This uses [Enumerable.Range](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range(v=vs.100).aspx) to create 10 consecutive numbers starting at 4. This example works with .NET 4 and above, earlier versions require a string array as the second parameter (i.e. `.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray()`).

Comment: But this does not print `then 13` part my opinion, isn't it? That's why `Enumerable.Range(4, 10)` would be better

Comment: @SonerGönül: Thanks, fixed. As the saying goes: *There are two hard things in computer science: cache invalidation, naming things, and off-by-one errors.*

Answer (score 1):

You can try with below code:

```
for (start = 4; start < 13; start++)
{
    Console.Write(start + " then ");
}
Console.Write(start);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: "Hope it helps"... you could at least explain your code.

Comment: You can stop for loop when start<13 then you can add one more console write outside the loop which can add only start value without then.

Comment: @Akhilesh great idea. Although the code is one line redundant, I like it because you avoid adding an if inside the loop. That improves performance when you iterate thousands of times.

Comment: Thanks @derloopkat yeah and performance is always a factor while implementing any code!

Answer (score 1):

After I kept trying, I came out with this code which seemed to do the trick.

```
        int start;
        int start1 = 13;
        for (start = 4; start <= 12; start++)


            Console.Write(start + " then ");
        Console.Write(start1);
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick if you want a one liner:

```
string result = string.Join(" then ", Enumerable.Range(4, 10).ToArray());
```

Comment: see that @Heinzi has already left a similar response... Sorry!

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
for (int start = 4; start <= 13; start++)
{
    if (start == 13 )
    {
        Console.Write("13");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.Write(start + " then ");
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: This works only when I omit the first and last curly braces. Otherwise it only prints "4 then". Any  reason as to why this happens?